# C++ While/ do while loop not pausing on a cin

Tags: c++, debugging, while-loop, do-while

No matter what I seem to do I cannot get the code to pause on either cin for feet or inches. I have tried using cin.clear and cin.ignore but the previous cin is a string

```
double inches = 0.0;
double feet = 0.0;

do 
{
    cout << "Please enter your height in feet:" << endl;
    cin >> feet;

    if  (feet > 2 && feet < 8)
    {
        cout << "Thank you!" << endl;
        break;
    }
    else if (feet < 2 || feet > 8)
    {
        cout << "You must be between 2 and 7 feet" << endl;
        
    }
} while (heightB);

while (heightB)
{
    cout << "\nPlease enter the inches:" << endl;
    cin >> inches;

    if (inches < 0 || inches > 11)
    {
        cout << "\nInches must be between 0 and 11" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Thank you!" << endl;
        break;
    }

}

total_inches = feet * 12 + inches;
cout << "Your total height in inches is: " << total_inches << endl;
```

Comment: _`... } while (heightB);

while (heightB) { ...`_ How do you expect that the second loop would ever be entered with these condiitons?

Comment: Regardless of the flaws with the second loop. There is a lot more code in here but trying to copy it all just made problems for the formatting and I have not used stack overflow enough to be able to fix it.  The main problem I have is that even if I use a break point to stop the code at the 2nd loop the cin still gets skipped. I'm new to programming and the only way I can fix a lot of problems is by starting them one step at a time and my first identifiable problem is that my cin. Also in regards to the heightB it is a global bool that is currently set to true. Its just how uni told me to do.

Comment: "_!'m new to programming and the only way I can fix a lot of problems is by starting them one step at a time_" - That sounds like something an experienced programmer would do. If you already approach problems this way, keep it up.

Comment: @Mr_Basal Post a [mcve] that reproduces the problem please, otherwise it's hard to help you in diagnosing the problem. So the 2nd loop should be entered, when `break;` is called in the 1st one. But it would be better though you copy a minimum of compilable code that reproduces the problem. Tips on code formatting are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: Ty for trying to help @πάνταῥεῖ and ty for the advice Ted. I figured out where I went wrong and it wasn't even in the code I sent haha

Answer (score 1):

Solved my own issue, turns out the issue was never in this. Simply I had made a rookie error due to an inexperience with strings. I used cin >> name for a string just before this. Instead I needed to use getline(cin, name) in order to get all of the text.

Because I didn't do that my loops were just endlessly looping.

Answer (score 0):

I slightly modified your code to make it executable and it is working as expected without any problem.

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    int main(){ 
        bool heightB = 1;
        double inches = 0.0;
        double feet = 0.0;
        double total_inches = 0.0;
        do 
        {
            cout << "Please enter your height in feet:" << endl;
            cin >> feet;
    
            if  (feet > 2 && feet < 8)
            {
                cout << "Thank you!" << endl;
                break;
            }
            else if (feet < 2 || feet > 8)
            {
                cout << "You must be between 2 and 7 feet" << endl;
                
            }
        } while (heightB);
    
        while (heightB)
        {
            cout << "\nPlease enter the inches:" << endl;
            cin >> inches;
    
            if (inches < 0 || inches > 11)
            {
                cout << "\nInches must be between 0 and 11" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Thank you!" << endl;
                break;
            }
    
        }
        
        total_inches = feet * 12 + inches;
        cout << "Your total height in inches is: " << total_inches << endl;
        
        return 0;
    }
```